# Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error pjsip

Tags: ios, xcode, pjsip

I'm trying to build this SIP application using PJSIP.

When I compile I get this error and no idea why or how something is duplicated.
I checked the:
Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
Build Phases -> Compile Sources

for duplicates but there isn't any.

Here is the error:

```
ignoring file /Users/kaanersan/Gogo/Gogo/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/kaanersan/Gogo/Gogo/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a

duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/UINavigationController+CustomAnimation.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/UINavigationController+CustomAnimation.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/UINavigationController+CustomAnimation.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+CustomMethods.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSString+CustomMethods.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIHTTPRequest.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIHTTPRequest.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIInputStream.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIInputStream.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIInputStream.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASINetworkQueue.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASINetworkQueue.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASINetworkQueue.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/RoundedRectView.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/RoundedRectView.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/RoundedRectView.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelpCell.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelpCell.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelpCell.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/InputCell.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/InputCell.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/InfoViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/InfoViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/SignInViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/SignInViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ConnectViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ConnectViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ConnectViewController.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ring.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ring.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ring.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSNotificationAdditions.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSNotificationAdditions.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/NSNotificationAdditions.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/Reachability.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/dtmf.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/dtmf.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/APIManager.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/APIManager.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/APIManager.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
duplicate symbol _kSIPCallState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

duplicate symbol _kSIPRegState in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

duplicate symbol _kSIPMwiInfo in:
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIDataDecompressor.o
    /Users/kaanersan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gogo-haciurlkiibxaffblggckauokhyf/Build/Intermediates/Gogo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Gogo.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o

ld: 126 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I had to cut out some parts of the error since it didn't fit into the question but I believe the most important part is the last part anyways and that's the red error, the rest are warnings.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

ASIDataDecompressor.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <zlib.h>

@interface ASIDataDecompressor : NSObject {
    BOOL streamReady;
    z_stream zStream;
}

// Convenience constructor will call setupStream for you
+ (id)decompressor;

// Uncompress the passed chunk of data
- (NSData *)uncompressBytes:(Bytef *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length error:(NSError **)err;

// Convenience method - pass it some deflated data, and you'll get inflated data back
+ (NSData *)uncompressData:(NSData*)compressedData error:(NSError **)err;

// Convenience method - pass it a file containing deflated data in sourcePath, and it will write inflated data to destinationPath
+ (BOOL)uncompressDataFromFile:(NSString *)sourcePath toFile:(NSString *)destinationPath error:(NSError **)err;

// Sets up zlib to handle the inflating. You only need to call this yourself if you aren't using the convenience constructor 'decompressor'
- (NSError *)setupStream;

// Tells zlib to clean up. You need to call this if you need to cancel inflating part way through
// If inflating finishes or fails, this method will be called automatically
- (NSError *)closeStream;

@property (assign, readonly) BOOL streamReady;
@end
```

ASIDataDecompressor.m:

```
#import "ASIDataDecompressor.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

#define DATA_CHUNK_SIZE 262144 // Deal with gzipped data in 256KB chunks

@interface ASIDataDecompressor ()
+ (NSError *)inflateErrorWithCode:(int)code;
@end;

@implementation ASIDataDecompressor

+ (id)decompressor
{
    ASIDataDecompressor *decompressor = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
    [decompressor setupStream];
    return decompressor;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (streamReady) {
        [self closeStream];
    }
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSError *)setupStream
{
    if (streamReady) {
        return nil;
    }
    // Setup the inflate stream
    zStream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    zStream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    zStream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    zStream.avail_in = 0;
    zStream.next_in = 0;
    int status = inflateInit2(&zStream, (15+32));
    if (status != Z_OK) {
        return [[self class] inflateErrorWithCode:status];
    }
    streamReady = YES;
    return nil;
}

- (NSError *)closeStream
{
    if (!streamReady) {
        return nil;
    }
    // Close the inflate stream
    streamReady = NO;
    int status = inflateEnd(&zStream);
    if (status != Z_OK) {
        return [[self class] inflateErrorWithCode:status];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)uncompressBytes:(Bytef *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length error:(NSError **)err
{
    if (length == 0) return nil;

    NSUInteger halfLength = length/2;
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:length+halfLength];

    int status;

    zStream.next_in = bytes;
    zStream.avail_in = (unsigned int)length;
    zStream.avail_out = 0;

    NSInteger bytesProcessedAlready = zStream.total_out;
    while (zStream.avail_in != 0) {

        if (zStream.total_out-bytesProcessedAlready >= [outputData length]) {
            [outputData increaseLengthBy:halfLength];
        }

        zStream.next_out = (Bytef*)[outputData mutableBytes] + zStream.total_out-bytesProcessedAlready;
        zStream.avail_out = (unsigned int)([outputData length] - (zStream.total_out-bytesProcessedAlready));

        status = inflate(&zStream, Z_NO_FLUSH);

        if (status == Z_STREAM_END) {
            break;
        } else if (status != Z_OK) {
            if (err) {
                *err = [[self class] inflateErrorWithCode:status];
            }
            return nil;
        }
    }

    // Set real length
    [outputData setLength: zStream.total_out-bytesProcessedAlready];
    return outputData;
}


+ (NSData *)uncompressData:(NSData*)compressedData error:(NSError **)err
{
    NSError *theError = nil;
    NSData *outputData = [[ASIDataDecompressor decompressor] uncompressBytes:(Bytef *)[compressedData bytes] length:[compressedData length] error:&theError];
    if (theError) {
        if (err) {
            *err = theError;
        }
        return nil;
    }
    return outputData;
}

+ (BOOL)uncompressDataFromFile:(NSString *)sourcePath toFile:(NSString *)destinationPath error:(NSError **)err
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];

    // Create an empty file at the destination path
    if (![fileManager createFileAtPath:destinationPath contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil]) {
        if (err) {
            *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASICompressionError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decompression of %@ failed because we were to create a file at %@",sourcePath,destinationPath],NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,nil]];
        }
        return NO;
    }

    // Ensure the source file exists
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sourcePath]) {
        if (err) {
            *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASICompressionError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decompression of %@ failed the file does not exist",sourcePath],NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,nil]];
        }
        return NO;
    }

    UInt8 inputData[DATA_CHUNK_SIZE];
    NSData *outputData;
    NSInteger readLength;
    NSError *theError = nil;


    ASIDataDecompressor *decompressor = [ASIDataDecompressor decompressor];

    NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:sourcePath];
    [inputStream open];
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:destinationPath append:NO];
    [outputStream open];

    while ([decompressor streamReady]) {

        // Read some data from the file
        readLength = [inputStream read:inputData maxLength:DATA_CHUNK_SIZE]; 

        // Make sure nothing went wrong
        if ([inputStream streamStatus] == NSStreamEventErrorOccurred) {
            if (err) {
                *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASICompressionError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decompression of %@ failed because we were unable to read from the source data file",sourcePath],NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,[inputStream streamError],NSUnderlyingErrorKey,nil]];
            }
            [decompressor closeStream];
            return NO;
        }
        // Have we reached the end of the input data?
        if (!readLength) {
            break;
        }

        // Attempt to inflate the chunk of data
        outputData = [decompressor uncompressBytes:inputData length:readLength error:&theError];
        if (theError) {
            if (err) {
                *err = theError;
            }
            [decompressor closeStream];
            return NO;
        }

        // Write the inflated data out to the destination file
        [outputStream write:(Bytef*)[outputData bytes] maxLength:[outputData length]];

        // Make sure nothing went wrong
        if ([inputStream streamStatus] == NSStreamEventErrorOccurred) {
            if (err) {
                *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASICompressionError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decompression of %@ failed because we were unable to write to the destination data file at %@",sourcePath,destinationPath],NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,[outputStream streamError],NSUnderlyingErrorKey,nil]];
            }
            [decompressor closeStream];
            return NO;
        }

    }

    [inputStream close];
    [outputStream close];

    NSError *error = [decompressor closeStream];
    if (error) {
        if (err) {
            *err = error;
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}


+ (NSError *)inflateErrorWithCode:(int)code
{
    return [NSError errorWithDomain:NetworkRequestErrorDomain code:ASICompressionError userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Decompression of data failed with code %d",code],NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,nil]];
}

@synthesize streamReady;
@end
```

Comment: `ASIDataDecompressor` seems to include symbols from other implementation files. What does the file look like?

Comment: Editing question to include .h and .m of ASIDataDecompressor.

Comment: It's probably due to some funky include or erroneous definition statement about `kSIPCallState`, `kSIPRegState` or `kSIPMwiInfo`, but it doesn't seem to be in ASIDataDecompressor. It's necessarily from `ASIHTTPRequest` or something it includes.

Comment: yeah, it was those variables being defined more than once! So I moved them to a different class and using them from there. Thanks so much, this fixed the problem!

Comment: I wish XCode's errors were easier to understand. If you post something along the lines of your above comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: the errors are from the linker program `ld`, which is admittedly the weakest link of error reporting in the Xcode toolchain. The compiler itself, `clang`, is notorious for the quality of its error messages (at least when compared to other C, C++ or Objective-C compilers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to some funky include or erroneous definition statement about `kSIPCallState`, `kSIPRegState` or `kSIPMwiInfo`, but it doesn't seem to be in ASIDataDecompressor. It's necessarily from `ASIHTTPRequest` or something it includes.

Reading the error message shows that only three symbols are duplicated (`kSIPCallState`, `kSIPRegState` or `kSIPMwiInfo`) and they always involve `ASIDataDecompressor`. Looking from there where there could be duplicate symbols is your best shot at debugging linker errors.

Answer (score 2):

i too had this same problem and searching for the duplicate symbols from the error log and replacing them solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried below steps to solve the problem:

1. I tried to run the build for i386 architecture using below mentioned command:

   > export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer ARCH="-arch i386" CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" ./configure-iphone
   >   make dep && make clean && make
2. Delete the Derive data from Xcode Preferences.
3. Set the correct header path in Xcode:

   ```
   $(SRCROOT)/../../../../pjlib/include
   $(SRCROOT)/../../../../pjlib-util/include
   $(SRCROOT)/../../../../pjmedia/include
   $(SRCROOT)/../../../../pjnath/include
   $(SRCROOT)/../../../../pjsip/include
   ```